# A regular 12-gon ABCDEFGHIJKL is inscribed into a circle of radius 12. Find the perimeter of the pentagon ACFHK.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I tried to draw everything, and then hope that a part of the pentagon (1/5) of it was 60 degrees, and then you know that the part would be an equilateral triangle. (The radii of the circle would be 2 sides, and therefore the third would also be 14). This did not turn out to be 60 degrees, and I am stuck.

Comment: Draw an altitude of one of your triangles and use trig.

Comment: Ah, did not think of that!

Comment: @MichaelBurr Can you put an answer to make sure that I am correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is a good one.

The vertices of the dodecagon are $360^\circ/12 = 30^\circ$ apart around the circle. From this you can see that some parts inside the pentagon are indeed equilateral triangles, whereas other parts are isosceles right triangles.

It should be straightforward to work out the <strike>area</strike> length of the outer side of each part and sum to get the total <strike>area</strike> perimeter. (*Edited after comments.*)

[image]

Comment: My question asks for perimeter, not area.

Comment: But nonetheless your solution gave me a hint. :)

Comment: I apologise for giving the wrong measurement, but I'm happy my answer was helpful.